# Jest + SCSS @import issue (css modules)

Tags: reactjs, sass, jestjs, babeljs, css-modules

I tried to set up my jest runner to work properly with scss `@impport` statatement (inside css modules in my React app).
but unfortunately, I get an error each time I run a test script. I tried different solutions from the StackOverflow similar tickets, but it didn't help me.

**example of my error:**

[image]

**my jest.config.js:**

```
module.exports = {
transform: {
    "^.+\\.(jsx?|tsx?)$": "<rootDir>/.jest/transform.ts",
},
testURL: 'http://localhost:6006/',
testRegex: "((\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.(jsx?|tsx?)$",
preset: 'jest-puppeteer',
moduleFileExtensions: [
    "scss",
    "ts",
    "tsx",
    "js",
    "jsx",
    "json",
    "node"
],
moduleDirectories: ["node_modules", "src"],
moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.(jpg | ico | jpeg | png | gif | eot | otf | webp | svg | ttf | woff | woff2 | mp4 | webm | wav | mp3 | m4a | aac | oga)$ ': '<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js',
    '\\.(css | scss)$': 'identity-obj-proxy'
},
transformIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules'],
setupFilesAfterEnv: [
    "<rootDir>/.jest/register-context.ts",
    "<rootDir>/.storybook/setupTests.ts"
]
};
```

**transform.ts file:**

```
module.exports = require('babel-jest').createTransformer({
    presets: [
        ['@babel/preset-env', { targets: { node: 'current' }, modules: 'commonjs' }],
        '@babel/preset-react',
        '@babel/preset-typescript',
    ],
    plugins: [
        'require-context-hook',
        '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
        '@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs'
    ],
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use spaces in the module name mapper regex. For example, instead of:

```
moduleNameMapper: {
  '\\.(css | scss)$': 'identity-obj-proxy'
},
```

Use this:

```
moduleNameMapper: {
  '\\.(css|scss)$': 'identity-obj-proxy'
},
```

I've never used identity-obj-proxy, I didn't tested it, but as I could read about, it does a similar task of a common file mapper like this:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  process(src, filename, config, options) {
    return 'module.exports = ' + JSON.stringify(path.basename(filename)) + ';';
  },
};
```

Comment: `identity-obj-proxy` isn't really a "common" file mapper. It uses es6 `Proxy` to return the property key (accessed on the object) as a string.